# greatest-n-per-group in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there any way in hibernate to get greatest record from a group.
In my table I have three columns(error_id, transaction_id, phone) I want to apply order by clause on transaction_id and then make group on basis of phone and then want to get top record from each group.

Any suggestions for this type or query....
Thanx in Advance.

Comment: you can always reply on HQL to do any work which SQL can do for you

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from my search.

```
String msisdnQueryString = "SELECT DISTINCT table.phone FROM TABLE_NAME table";
Query msisdnQueryObject = session.createQuery(msisdnQueryString);
List msisdnList = msisdnQueryObject.list();

List<Long> transactionList = new ArrayList<Long>();
for(Object object : msisdnList){
    Long msisdn = Long.parseLong(object.toString());
    String transactionQueryString = "SELECT table.transactionId FROM TABLE_NAME table WHERE table.phone = "+msisdn+" ORDER BY table.transactionId DESC";
    Query transactionQueryObject = session.createQuery(transactionQueryString);
    transactionQueryObject.setFirstResult(0);
    transactionQueryObject.setMaxResults(1);
    List transactions =transactionQueryObject.list();
    if(transactions.size() > 0){
    transactionList.add((Long)transactions.get(0));
    }
}
```

It is a long process but it is working. If any one know better way to get such records then please post your answers.